# "Error: ValidationError: username: Path `username` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required."

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making a POST request to add a user and I get above error in Insomnia tool.
[image]

**User.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true },
email: { type: String, required: true },
password: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**User.js (controller)**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const newUser = new User({ username,email,password });

    newUser.save()
        .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please help.

EDIT 2 - 
I am using mongodb atlas. And I think the problem might be with my connection string. How do I specify database name and collection name in connection string URI?

Documentation says to put /dbname after clustername, but where do I specify collection-name?

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB connection established successfully');
})

const userRouter = require('./routes/user');

app.use('/users', userRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**.env**

```
ATLAS_URI=mongodb+srv://<my-username>:<my-password>@<my-cluster>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: Did you use a body parser middleware?

Comment: Yes I have used body parser

Comment: this is how your `ATLAS_URI` need to look like `ATLAS_URI='mongodb+srv://sandy:sandy12345@clusterName/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'`  you will get this `URL` from `MongoDB` only thing you need to  change here is Username and password. Question is Are you connected to `MongoDB` or not?

Comment: yes I did change the username, password and cluster link and here I have masked those things for privacy. And yes when the run the server it shows connection is successful

Answer (score 0):

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User(req.body);

    newUser.save()
        .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
});

module.exports = router;
```

give this a shot

Comment: can you send me the code for html page. I have faced similar problem. I am just figuring out how i solved it.

Comment: there is no html, I am trying to setup my backend and it only has bunch of js files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I restarted the Insomnia and it worked. Maybe the issue was in the "Header" part.